# Como mostrar várias imagens selecionada "input file"?

Tags: javascript, html, input

aqui está um exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/9714/

Quando seleciona 4 imagens diferentes, as 4 imagens são iguais ao mostrar na tela.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" multiple />
    <img id="blah" src="#" width="100" />

    <img id="blah1" src="#" width="100" />

    <img id="blah2" src="#" width="100" />

    <img id="blah3" src="#" width="100" />
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
 function readURL(input) {        

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
                $('#blah1').attr('src', e.target.result);
                $('#blah2').attr('src', e.target.result);
                $('#blah3').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
```

Comment: Têm muitas coisas que você pode melhorar ai. O primeiro é não usar divs diferentes para cada imagem. A outra é você ter que fazer um laço de repetição e pegar imagem por imagem. Vou analisar teu código e responder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem alguns defeitos no seu código; na minha visão, o correto seria você aprender como funciona e refazer. Segue esse código explicativo.

A primeira lógica de tudo é montar o html. O primeiro defeito encontrado no seu código é `<input type='file' id="imgInp" multiple />` onde você deferia ter definido a propriedade `name` para receber as chaves.

Corrigindo essa parte, você deve fazer algo parecido com isso

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple />
<div class="resultados"></div>
```

Outro problema no seu código é que você está criando 4 divs, cada uma para receber uma imagem diferente, outro defeito, já que você pode criar apenas uma div para receber os valores; trabalha igual, funciona e é melhor.

Para resolver isso, no código acima coloquei apenas uma div chamada `resultados` que vai receber todas as imagens.

Agora no seu Javascript é onde está o maior defeito. Você está jogando sempre a primeira chave para ambas as divs.

O correto é você fazer dessa maneira

```
  function readURL(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;

    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      } //verifica se os arquivos são imagens

      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (function(filei) {
        return function(e) {

          var tag = document.createElement('span');
          tag.innerHTML = ['<img src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(filei.name), '"/>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('resultados').insertBefore(tag, null);
        };
      })(f);
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', readURL, false);
```

Você pode visualizar esse código em ação no [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/9714/).

Comment: Está muito parecido com esse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069421/show-an-image-preview-before-upload/39223477#39223477

Comment: Não parece. Mas você pode marcar como duplicada, caso a comunidade acha que seja. Esse código eu uso no meu projeto. Ele foi baseado desse site https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: Valeu, ajudou aqui.